# how to disable re-login in iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have developed an app which is related with **signing in to an account** and people can also get registered in my app, since those user info will be stored in a **SQLite database**.

The problem is that, when the user **logs out** of the account and then **re-logs in**, the app asks the user to login again. I dont want this to happen, as it should remember the user name and password and should **login automatically**.

Does anyone know how to get this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `AppDelegate.m` file , add the `NSUserDefaults` method ...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([standardUserDefaults valueForKey:@"dbID"]==nil) {          
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:@"1" forKey:@"dbID"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }

}
```

and also you have sane the username and password save the `NSUserDefaults`.
and for log out functionality , add the code logout code where you want the logout the applications ...

```
-(IBAction)Logout :(id)sender {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"dbID"];   
    [NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
}
```

in the login time check the `dbID` is null then user login with the username and password. if the `dbID` is not `null` the login the old username and password.

if u are exit the without logout the applications , then store the dbID is "1" in the NSUserDefaults and redirect the view controller and For save the user name and password in the your logon time...for save

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"Your text field value" forKey:@"Username"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"Your text field value" forKey:@"password"];
```

read the

```
NSString * _UserName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Username"];
NSString * _password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password"];
```

username and password save the NSUserDefaults is indicated the u have store the username and password in NSUserDefaults.

if the you have logout the application by button , the make the NUll username and password save the NSUserDefaults .. like

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"" forKey:@"Username"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"" forKey:@"password"];
```

Comment: I've done exactly the same as u instructed me to, but when i try to login with the user name and password, close the application and come back to the login page, its not logging in automatically. Is there any other solution? and what do u mean by "save the username, password and NSUserDefaults" How am i supposed to do that?

Comment: @AjitKumar if u are exit the without logout the applications , then store the dbID is "1" in the NSUserDefaults and redirect the view controller.username and password save the NSUserDefaults is indicated the u have store the username and password in NSUserDefaults .See the edit answer..

Comment: So, u r asking me to store the username and password(set value) after the set objects and synchronise codes in appdelegate.m?

Comment: Ok. Now we are using setobjects first, then synchronise and then setvalue to store the username and password in appdelegate.m. Then what are those NSString codes u've mentioned there and where i've to use them?

Comment: actually i giving just example how to retrive the data from NSUserDefaults. you have also read the [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Username"] and compare the value.

Comment: After signing up, i just want the username and password to be stored in NSUser Defaults and when i click home button, it should automatically login without going to the login page. If u are very sure that it will work, please post me the entire code for it along with the classes where i've to import them.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSUserDefaults. This one will work fine

```
NSUserDefaults *rememberDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([[rememberDefault valueForKey:@"Autologin"] isEqualToString:@"Autologin_on"]) {
    btnAutoLogin.selected =NO;
}else {        
    btnAutoLogin.selected =YES;
}
```

In your Button Action Method :

```
-(IBAction)btnOnOffSwitch:(UIButton *)sender{ 

    if (sender.selected) {
        sender.selected = NO;
    }else {        
        sender.selected = YES;
    }    
}
```

and when you want to check use this:

```
NSUserDefaults *rememberDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if([[rememberDefault valueForKey:@"Autologin"] isEqualToString:@"Autologin_on"])

{

     write your code here. to push directly to your home screen. this should be checked in your login screen

}
```

Comment: If i write the 1st set of code related with NSUser defaults in the viewDidLoad part and if i write the next set of code in the button action method, will it work? And whats the use of checking that, as u've mentioned in the code below?

Comment: @Ajit Kumar:u need to check at the login screen whether the user is already logged in or not rite ? and it's just for auto login. use the same as you want. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

may b this will help you.

for your condition when user successfully login first time at that time make 1 dictionary for storing username , password and user id else make 3 different nsuserdefault object for this 3 types.

and when user comes again in that login screen check that nsuser default value is empty or has some value so if the value is there than it has already logsin and u can directly redirect him to next page .. else display the login page..

here i have write only the logic not source code so u can try it out your self and learn more :)..

hope this will help you.